# Value returned by calender.get( Calendar.HOUR ) is different from system clock time?

Tags: java, serialization

My system clock currently shows 9:54 AM as the time. However if I do the following:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Now: " 
                    + cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM) + " , " 
                    + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) + " , "
                    + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

I get the output:

```
Now: 0 , 7 , 53
```

So the AM/PM value is correct, and the minutes are correct, but the hour is returning a different time than my system clock.

What's causing this? I'm on Linux, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Have you considered using `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`?

Comment: Both the `HOUR` and `HOUR_OF_DAY` fetch me the proper result. Have you tried checking the `Locale`?

Comment: This may be related to your timezone settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the problem, and it was my fault.

I was serializing this class, saving it to a file, and then unserializing it and loading it from the file each time the program started.

The calendar member of my class was also being serialized and loaded from the file each time, and that's why the hour did not update since 7 am when the file was last saved:

```
public class Foo implements Serializable
{
   private final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
}
```

I've changed this variable to static, i.e:

```
public class Foo implements Serializable
{
   private final static Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
}
```

since static variables don't seem to be serialized, And now everything works.

Edit: Further testing has revealed, that even if you load the calendar at program start, its time doesn't update every second, so if you load program, and 5 mins later try to get current time, you will get the time from 5 mins ago. The solution is to always get the instance right before checking the time.